# Assignment in Newtonsoft.Json's implementation of JsonPath

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I have a JSON like this one:

```json
{
    "options": [
        {
            "price": 217,
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "price": 63,
            "quantity": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to query it with JsonPath to get the product of "price" and "quantity" for every element in the "options" array.

I use this [site](https://jsonpath.com/) to play around with the syntax. And I actually found a way to do it:

```
options[?(@.result = @.price * @.quantity)].result
```

This syntax adds a property 'result' to each element and stores the product in it like that:

```
[
  {
    "price": 217,
    "quantity": 2,
    "result": 434  // yay!
  },
  {
    "price": 63,
    "quantity": 5,
    "result": 315  // yay!
  }
]
```

So the final result is exactly what I want:

```
[
  434,
  315
]
```

I don't really need to set any properties. I just want the result like that.

The problem is - it doesn't work in the C# application (with Newtonsoft.Json). It can't parse the query.
I tried to introduce the property in JSON beforehand, it didn't work either.

```
json = JObject.Parse(@"{}"); // same JSON as above

var result = json.SelectTokens("options[?(@.result = @.price * @.quantity)].result"); // exception
```

Could you please help me to figure it out?

**Note:** I only have UI at my disposal. No access to code, no LINQ, no API calls. I just happened to know the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONPath syntax was not that well standardized for quite some time. So one implementation and what it does support can vastly differ from another (in particular the online tool which you have tried - I found it far more lax than JSONPath implementations I worked with). For example [this](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html) site which I usually use as reference for the syntax seems to be missing the options you have tried. And [this online validator](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/#) does not process this query expression as you expect.

Note that as stated in the [`JToken.SelectToken` Method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) doc:

> Selects a `JToken` using a `JPath` expression. Selects the token that matches the object path.

So it arguably should not support such syntax at all. And based on the tests in the [Newtonsoft.Json github repo](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master) such syntax is not tested (at least in tests I have looked through) and it is safe to assume that it is not supported.

So I suggest to just iterate elements of the array and calculate needed value:

```
var results = new List<int>();
foreach (var elem in json["options"])
{
    results.Add(elem["price"].Value<int>() * elem["quantity"].Value<int>());
}
```

Also note that there is [pending IETF specification](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base-21.html) and according to it JSONPath is query-only and does not support such syntax.

Comment: Thank you for quick response! I can't actualy iterate it in code. The whole point is that I only can use the application as user, filling text form in UI with JSONPath. It's just a coincidence that i know the underlying implementation. Of course I would just use LINQ if I could.

Comment: ^^ Would have been a good point to add to the Q, so people do not waste time on authoring "workaround" answers.

Comment: @SlyRedbeard then I'm afraid there is not much you can do. Based on the tests in the [Newtonsoft.Json github repo](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master) this syntax is not tested and I is safe to assume is not supported.

Comment: @GuruStron thank you for your time. At least I will stop trying now :).

Comment: @GuruStron "First of all JSONPath syntax is not that good standardized".  Not sure what you mean here.  Please see my answer, which contains a link to the pending IETF specification.

Answer (score 2):

JSON Path is a query-only syntax.  It can only return values that are already in the JSON document; temp vars and other such things are not supported (though I like the idea).

There is a pending specification (just waiting on IETF to issue an RFC number): https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base-21.html.  Once that's official, I expect many implementations will move to support it.  For now, in .NET, only my *JsonPath.Net* implements the spec.

There are a number of issues in the Github repo where we're managing the spec that we're considering for a "v2".  I expect this assignment / creation of temp vars thing would be a good one if you'd like to add it.